# Probability of being of the same team $n$ number of times

Tags: probability

There is a $42\%$ chance my husband and I will be chosen to be on the same team on any given night.  We play the game ten times.  What is the probability we are on the same team more than $50\%$ of the time?

I think it is $P(10) + P(9,1) + P(8,2) + P(7,3) + P(6,4)$ but the percentage is so small less than $1\%$, so I think I might be missing something.

Comment: I think you are right, your probability is $P=0.42^{10}+0.42^{9}+0.42^{8}+0.42^{7}+0.42^{6}$, so around 0.93%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take under consideration the different possibilities the the events can happen in, so the probability becomes:

$$0.42^{10}+{{10}\choose{1}}0.42^9 0.58^1+{{10}\choose{2}}0.42^8 0.58^2+{{10}\choose{3}}0.42^7 0.58^3+{{10}\choose{4}}0.42^6 0.58^4 \approx 20.161 \%.$$

Comment: Shouldnt the 2nd term be $C^{10}_{1}\ 0.42^9 \ 0.58^1$, and the 3rd term be $C^{10}_{2} \ 0.42^8 \ 0.58^2$ etc?  Intuitively with only 10 flips of a slightly biased coin, Prob(6+ heads) should be < 1/2 but not be as tiny as 0.18%...

Comment: True, I will adjust.

Comment: @Expatec Please see the new version of the answer as there was a big mistake in the first version.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not  correct.

I found that to be $$1-\text {binomcdf }(10,.42,5)=.2016$$

The probability is expected to be very small because your probability of being on the team is less than $50\%$ and you want to be chosen for more than $50\%$ of the time.

It is not going to happen too often.

Comment: Thank you, but shouldn't it be 1-binomcdf(10,.42,6)? As 5 is not not more than 50%?

Comment: Note that binomcdf(10,.42,6) includes  6 so if you find 1-binomcdf(10,.42,6) you are excluding 6.